# conditions as boolean expression using shift operations

Tags: bit, bit-shift, arithmetic-expressions

I learnt that condition like: (x is 4 bytes)

```
if (x) a = y else a = z;
```

can be expressed as:

```
a = ((x<<31)>>31)&y + (((!x)<<31)>>31)&z
```

I can understand what it does, but I think it is limited under the circumstance that `x` has all its bits of 0 (evaluated as 0, 00..00) or right most bit of 1 and rest of bits as 0 (evaluated as 1, like 00...1)
But since any non-zero value can be evaluated as true (e.g 00..010..0), then above expression doesn't work.

So how can we use shift operations in this case?

Comment: `!!x`.  You can also take advantage of unsigned arithmetic to avoid the shifts:  `(0U-!!x)&y | (0U-!x)&z`

Comment: @ChrisDodd  you mean first part should be (((!(!x))<<31)>>31)&y?